# Where can I download b°wide NodePack?

Tags: node-editor

All links I`ve found are dead as for now. Lost this pack during setting a new PC=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/70570
It's from bashi, the links on his homepage don't work anymore. But he uploaded it to blendswap as well.